# Trouble running Blender on Paperspace Virtual Machines

Tags: versions

I have looked at related questions about virtual machines, but I have not found an answer to this. Blender is less responsive (when I move the mouse or press a hotkey, the object's movement is slow and jerky) on our virtual machines. Is this inherent in Blender itself (does it just not work well with virtual machines, or with our virtual machines, or is there a way to optimize the two together? (We are also piloting on a different virtual machine, and so far it seems maybe a little smoother, but we're keeping an eye on it.) Or, does this work better with some versions of Blender than others?

Thank you!

Lisa

Comment: Blender needs graphics hardware supporting OpenGL at least 3.3. I would suspect problems may be in the way virtual machines are handling that.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the insight, and will follow up.